# How to plot this region?

Tags: parametric-functions, regions, plotting

Consider the $2\times 2$ matrices 
\begin{align}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and the vector
\begin{align}
u=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta \\ \sin\theta\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
For all $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, and given $A$ and $B$, consider the set of 2-D points whose co-ordinates are given as $(u^TAu,u^TBu)$, How do I plot this region?

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{u.a.u, u.b.u}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]`

Answer (score 7):

Consider

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
B = {{5, 6}, {7, 8}};
```

Then

```
ParametricPlot[
 {
  {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}.A.{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]},
  {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}.B.{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}
  },
 {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Or more generally,

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
B = {{5, 6}, {x, 8}};

ParametricPlot[
 Table[{{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}.A.{Cos[θ], 
      Sin[θ]}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}.B.{Cos[θ],
       Sin[θ]}}, {x, -9, 9}] // Evaluate, {θ, 0, 
  2 π}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit...

Comment: Probably, this is not the right place, but am just trying. Any explanation or thoughts as to why this looks like a ellipse?

Comment: It is an ellipse.  Here {x,y}.A.{x,y} is a quadratic form in x and y:  a x^2 + b x + c y^2 + d6 + e, and likewise for matrix B.  Thus the general solutions are the quadratics (circle, ellipse, hyperbola, etc.)... however for our case, {x,y} = {Cos[Theta],Sin[Theta]} and hence with bound norm of 1.0, restricting the solutions to generalized ellipses:  ellipses, circles, (degenerate) lines, and (degenerate) points.  Let A = B to see one degenerate case.

Answer (score 3):

> Any explanation or thoughts as to why this looks like a ellipse?

```
A = Array[a, {2, 2}];
B = Array[b, {2, 2}];
u = {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
({u.A.u, u.B.u} // TrigReduce // Simplify)
  /. {a[i_, j_] :> Subscript[a, i, j], b[i_, j_] :> Subscript[b, i, j]}
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(a_{1,2}+a_{2,1}\right) \sin (2 t)+\left(a_{1,1}-a_{2,2}\right) \cos (2 t)+a_{1,1}+a_{2,2}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(b_{1,2}+b_{2,1}\right) \sin (2 t)+\left(b_{1,1}-b_{2,2}\right) \cos (2 t)+b_{1,1}+b_{2,2}\right)\right\}$$

So the plot is a translated [Lissajous figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) with both frequencies equal to $2$. As the frequencies are equal, the figure is an ellipse.